# Upgrade my town hall to level 10

Tags: clash-of-clans

I want to make an upgrade to Town Hall 10. I have the gold needed, but  my storage is not up to the required amount. I have 4 million in my storage and another 1 million in my clan castle to make 5 million, enough to upgrade my town hall to level 10. My storage max capacity is 4.6 million at the moment.

Can I proceed to the upgrade ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, *technically* no, you cannot. You need to transfer your gold (in the Clan Caste) in your storage first, then upgrade your town hall. Because you don't have enough capacity in your storage, you won't be able to have the required amount of gold.

What I **strongly** recommend is that you **do not** upgrade you Town Hall (lvl 9 I assume) until you maxed **everything else**. Your defenses, troops, walls, heroes should be maxed *before* you upgrade your Town Hall, for the simple reason that it will be way harder to farm. That includes maxing your gold storage.

General tip : **Do not rush into maxing your Town Hall**. You'd do better to max everything else before upgrading to the next level.

Comment: Please what app to make video while attacking on coc

Comment: While this comment is quite true and strongly recommended; I would like to add that 'lego' walls should be fine (1 below max for th9), getting full lava walls is hardly necessary unless you are an extremely dedicated player